# ASP.NET Core WebAPI : Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, scrutor

I am building an ASP.NET Core WebAPI application, it is working perfectly fine with the below setup

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var settings = Configuration.Get<Settings>();
        CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(settings.CosmosDB.EndpointUrl, settings.CosmosDB.PrimaryKey);
        CosmosDbContainerFactory cosmosDbClientFactory = new CosmosDbContainerFactory(client, settings.CosmosDB.DatabaseName, settings.CosmosDB.Containers);

        services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbContainerFactory>(cosmosDbClientFactory);
        services.AddTransient<IFamilyService, FamilyService>();
        services.AddTransient<IFamilyRepository, FamilyRepository>();

        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

But while trying to replace the manual service registration with Scrutor Scan, like mentioned below

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var settings = Configuration.Get<Settings>();
        CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(settings.CosmosDB.EndpointUrl, settings.CosmosDB.PrimaryKey);
        CosmosDbContainerFactory cosmosDbClientFactory = new CosmosDbContainerFactory(client, settings.CosmosDB.DatabaseName, settings.CosmosDB.Containers);

        services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbContainerFactory>(cosmosDbClientFactory);

        services.Scan(s => s
            .FromAssembliesOf(typeof(IApiAssemblyMarker))
            .AddClasses(false)
            .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Append)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithTransientLifetime()
            ); 

        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

I am getting the following error

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: FBAuthDemoAPI.Services.Contract.IFamilyService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: FBAuthDemoAPI.Services.Implementation.FamilyService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient' while attempting to activate 'FBAuthDemoAPI.CosmosDBFactory.CosmosDbContainerFactory'.

```
public interface IFamilyService
{   
}

public class FamilyService : IFamilyService
{
    private readonly IFamilyRepository _familyRepository;

    public FamilyService(IFamilyRepository familyRepository)
    {
        this._familyRepository = familyRepository;
    }
}   

public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
}   

public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly ICosmosDbContainerFactory _cosmosDbContainerFactory;

    public abstract string DatabaseName { get; }
    public abstract string ContainerName { get; }

    protected GenericRepository(ICosmosDbContainerFactory cosmosDbContainerFactory)
    {
        this._cosmosDbContainerFactory = cosmosDbContainerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ICosmosDbContainerFactory));
        this._container = this._cosmosDbContainerFactory.GetContainer(ContainerName)._container;
    }
}   

public interface IFamilyRepository : IGenericRepository<Family>
{
}

public class FamilyRepository : GenericRepository<Family>, IFamilyRepository
{       
    public override string DatabaseName => "FamilyDB";
    public override string ContainerName => "Family";

    public FamilyRepository(ICosmosDbContainerFactory factory) :
        base(factory)
    {
    }   
}
```

What is the issue and How do I fix this?

**Update:**: Having registered the classes shown below, it started working, but I'm not understanding why it failed when registering with the Single instance like mentioned above, Is it due to the limitation of **Scrutor** library?

```
        var cosmosDBSettings = new CosmosDBSettings();
        configration.Bind(CosmosDBSettings.SectionName, cosmosDBSettings);
        services.AddSingleton(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.Create(cosmosDBSettings));

        services.Scan(scan => scan
          .FromAssembliesOf(typeof(IApiAssemblyMarker))
            .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ICosmosDbContainerFactory>()) // Filter classes
                .AsSelfWithInterfaces()
                .WithSingletonLifetime()
            .AddClasses(x => x.AssignableTo(typeof(IGenericRepository<>))) // Can close generic types
                .AsMatchingInterface()
                .WithScopedLifetime()
            .AddClasses(x => x.AssignableTo(typeof(IFamilyService))) // Can close generic types
                .AsMatchingInterface()
                .WithScopedLifetime());
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the exception that in `FamilyService` you need to change the constructor arguments as there is a missing dependency? Which is wierd, because you have clearly registered an `ICosmosDbContainerFactory` implementation as a singleton.

Comment: Your code samples and the exception don't match, which makes me believe that there's some code you are not showing us. The exception states that MS.DI is "attempting to activate 'CosmosDbContainerFactory'". This indicates that MS.DI is actually *creating* that class; but your question shows how you are registering an already created instance. That code will not lead to that exception. What are you not showing us?

Comment: @Steven, I have updated the question, please refer the "Update" section. Do you have any suggestions?